# 4 Elements Responsive that wrap into a single column

Tags: html, css

I have a simple email sign up list that I'd like to be responsive.
Currently, when it wraps it just wraps each individual element as it overflows.

The functionality I want is when the first element overflows that the whole form goes from vertical layout to horizontal.

Ex: (for wide screen lengths)

```
[Input Name]  [Input Email]   [Input Country]   [Submit]
```

It's not currently very responsive because as the screen size gets smaller or you move to a mobile device it will look like this:

```
   [Input Name]  
[Input Email]   [Input Country]   [Submit]
```

Or Like:

```
   [Input Name]  
[Input Email]   
  [Input Country]   [Submit]
```

It gets distorted.  I want all the elements either on one line, or on 4 different lines.

For small screen widths (ie: mobile), it should look like this:

```
[Input Name.   ]  
[Input Email.  ]   
[Input Country ]   
[Submit.       ]
```

Any idea how to accomplish this using HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a media query to set a specific page width that handles the transition from block to inline.

```css
input {
  width: 95%;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
  }
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
  <input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use max-width property on the input element with the other property
     input[type="text"] {max-width:95%;}
or you can use css media query
     @media screen and (min-width: 
     440px)
     {
     input {width: 400px; 
     display:block;}
     }